# ffmpeg error: Can't make thumbnail from video in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, ffmpeg, cloud-storage

I can't seem to create a thumbnail from a video file in javascript. I keep getting the following error:

```
ChildProcessError: `/workspace/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/linux-x64/ffmpeg -ss 0 -I valid-video-link -f image2 -vframes 1 -vf scale=10:10 -update 1 /tmp/thumbnails/TTT1633248087A995.jpg` failed with code 1`
```

Here is my code:

```
const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const promise = spawn(ffmpegPath, ['-ss', '0', '-i', fileUrl, '-f', 'image2', '-vframes', '1', '-vf', `scale=10:10`, `-update`, `1`, tempLocalThumbnailFile]);
```

The promise comes up undefined.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue; the directory it was being uploaded to didn't exist.